# Multiple texture units in shader vs multiple semitransparent textured meshes - performance

Tags: ios, opengl-es

There is a 2D scene using OpenGL ES 2.0. I need to draw a quad with a number of semitransparent textures (kind of noise), that rotate with different phases to simulate an organic like effect. I assume there are two options:

- Drawing one quad, using a shader with multiple samplers and rotating texture coordinates for each sampler (for example in the vertex shader).
- Drawing multiple overlying and rotating quads, binding a different texture to each mesh (and a much simpler shading program).

The quad (or quads) will be drawn using vertex arrays:

`glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);`

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, index, numVertex);

The first option seems more efficient because there is only one mesh and all the blending is done once in the fragment shader. There is only one call to glDrawArrays().

On the other hand, the second option implies a much simpler fragment shader, with one texture look up (however called N - times for each quad).

In both options there is the same number of texture bindings but in the first option, all textures are bound to different texture units.

I would like to know your opinion about the performance for each of these options.

Comment: *"On the other hand, the second option implies a much simpler fragment shader"* - Yeah, just that this simpler fragment shader is executed multiple times.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean by "(however called N - times for each quad)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no question here, using multiple texture units will give you better performance. Generally speaking, the fewer trips your data have to take down the pipeline the quicker they will finish. So if you can cram more operations into a single fragment shader more power to you.

The only reason you might consider doing otherwise is if you run into hardware limitations like the number of temporary registers or instruction slots used or texture image units, none of which are relevant in your simple example. Even on the most pathetic hardware capable of implementing OpenGL ES 2.0 you are guaranteed 8 texture units:

- const mediump int `gl_MaxVertexTextureImageUnits` = 0; // Vertex texture lookups are ***optional***
- const mediump int `gl_MaxCombinedTextureImageUnits` = 8;
- *const mediump int* **`gl_MaxTextureImageUnits` = 8;**

ES 2.0 does not have per-texture unit matrices, but you can supply your own using a uniform. Then in your vertex shader, you can multiply your texture coordinates by a matrix that defines your rotation and pass the result to your fragment shader in the form of separate sets of texture coordinates. This should be your preferred course of action up until you reach your texture image unit limit.